# Tokenize a "Braced Initializer List"-Style String in C++ (With Boost?)

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, boost-spirit, boost-tokenizer

I have a string (nested strings even) that are formatted like a C++ braced initializer list.  I want to tokenize them one level at a time into a vector of strings.

So when I input `"{one, two, three}"` to the function should output a three element vector

`"one"`,

`"two"`,

`"three"`

To complicate this, it needs to support quoted tokens and preserve nested lists:

Input String: `"{one, {2, \"three four\"}}, \"five, six\", {\"seven, eight\"}}"`

Output is a four element vector:

`"one"`,

`"{2, \"three four\"}"`,

`"five, six"`,

`"{\"seven, eight\"}"`

I've looked at a few other SO posts:

[Using Boost Tokenizer escaped_list_separator with different parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541561/using-boost-tokenizer-escaped-list-separator-with-different-parameters)

[Boost split not traversing inside of parenthesis or braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32792425/boost-split-not-traversing-inside-of-parenthesis-or-braces)

And used those to start a solution, but this seems slightly too complicated for the tokenizer (because of the braces):

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>

std::vector<std::string> TokenizeBracedList(const std::string& x)
{
  std::vector<std::string> tokens;

  std::string separator1("");
  std::string separator2(",\n\t\r");
  std::string separator3("\"\'");

  boost::escaped_list_separator<char> elements(separator1, separator2, separator3);
  boost::tokenizer<boost::escaped_list_separator<char>> tokenizer(x, elements);

  for(auto i = std::begin(tokenizer); i != std::end(tokenizer); ++i)
  {
    auto token = *i;
    boost::algorithm::trim(token);
    tokens.push_back(token);
  }

  return tokens;
}
```

With this, even in the trivial case, it doesn't strip the opening and closing braces.

Boost and C++17 are fair game for a solution.

Comment: How will you store the results? It doesn't make much sense to have a requirement to "preserve nested lists" and have a flat result type

Comment: Preservation of nested lists is requirement, but the return type is not a requirement.  The lists could be preserved as in my example, or through a nested data structure which further resolves them, but keeps their relationships intact.  Flat, as in my example, is suitable.  Just trying to keep the question focused on the problem at hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Simple (Flat) Take

Defining a flat data structure like:

```
using token  = std::string;
using tokens = std::vector<token>;
```

We can define an X3 parser like:

```
namespace Parser {
    using namespace boost::spirit::x3;

    rule<struct list_, token> item;

    auto quoted   = lexeme [ '"' >> *('\\' >> char_ | ~char_('"')) >> '"' ];
    auto bare     = lexeme [ +(graph-','-'}') ];

    auto list     = '{' >> (item % ',') >> '}';
    auto sublist  = raw [ list ];

    auto item_def = sublist | quoted | bare;

    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(item)
}
```

**<kbd>[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/koADnRsUdpqcZwl7)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using token  = std::string;
using tokens = std::vector<token>;

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

namespace Parser {
    using namespace boost::spirit::x3;

    rule<struct list_, token> item;

    auto quoted   = lexeme [ '"' >> *('\\' >> char_ | ~char_('"')) >> '"' ];
    auto bare     = lexeme [ +(graph-','-'}') ];

    auto list     = '{' >> (item % ',') >> '}';
    auto sublist  = raw [ list ];

    auto item_def = sublist | quoted | bare;

    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(item)
}

int main() {
    for (std::string const input : {
            R"({one, "five, six"})",
            R"({one, {2, "three four"}, "five, six", {"seven, eight"}})",
        })
    {
        auto f = input.begin(), l = input.end();

        std::vector<std::string> parsed;
        bool ok = phrase_parse(f, l, Parser::list, x3::space, parsed);

        if (ok) {
            std::cout << "Parsed: " << parsed.size() << " elements\n";
            for (auto& el : parsed) {
                std::cout << " - " << std::quoted(el, '\'') << "\n";
            }
        } else {
            std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
        }

        if (f != l)
            std::cout << "Remaining unparsed: " << std::quoted(std::string{f, l}) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Parsed: 2 elements
 - 'one'
 - 'five, six'
Parsed: 4 elements
 - 'one'
 - '{2, "three four"}'
 - 'five, six'
 - '{"seven, eight"}'
```

### Nested Data

Changing the datastructure to be a bit more specific/realistic:

```
namespace ast {
    using value = boost::make_recursive_variant<
            double,
            std::string,
            std::vector<boost::recursive_variant_>
        >::type;
    using list = std::vector<value>;
}
```

Now we can change the grammar, as we no longer need to treat `sublist` as if it is a string:

```
namespace Parser {
    using namespace boost::spirit::x3;

    rule<struct item_, ast::value> item;

    auto quoted   = lexeme [ '"' >> *('\\' >> char_ | ~char_('"')) >> '"' ];
    auto bare     = lexeme [ +(graph-','-'}') ];

    auto list     = x3::rule<struct list_, ast::list> {"list" }
                  = '{' >> (item % ',') >> '}';

    auto item_def = list | double_ | quoted | bare;

    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(item)
}
```

Everything "still works": **<kbd>[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Csmu8KldTk4Uvzma)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

namespace ast {
    using value = boost::make_recursive_variant<
            double,
            std::string,
            std::vector<boost::recursive_variant_>
        >::type;
    using list = std::vector<value>;
}

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

namespace Parser {
    using namespace boost::spirit::x3;

    rule<struct item_, ast::value> item;

    auto quoted   = lexeme [ '"' >> *('\\' >> char_ | ~char_('"')) >> '"' ];
    auto bare     = lexeme [ +(graph-','-'}') ];

    auto list     = x3::rule<struct list_, ast::list> {"list" }
                  = '{' >> (item % ',') >> '}';

    auto item_def = list | double_ | quoted | bare;

    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(item)
}

struct pretty_printer {
    using result_type = void;
    std::ostream& _os;
    int _indent;

    pretty_printer(std::ostream& os, int indent = 0) : _os(os), _indent(indent) {}

    void operator()(ast::value const& v) { boost::apply_visitor(*this, v); }

    void operator()(double v)            { _os << v; }
    void operator()(std::string s)       { _os << std::quoted(s); }
    void operator()(ast::list const& l)  {
        _os << "{\n";
        _indent += 2;
        for (auto& item : l) {
            _os << std::setw(_indent) << "";
            operator()(item);
           _os << ",\n";
        }
        _indent -= 2;
        _os << std::setw(_indent) << "" << "}";
    }
};

int main() {
    pretty_printer print{std::cout};

    for (std::string const input : {
            R"({one, "five, six"})",
            R"({one, {2, "three four"}, "five, six", {"seven, eight"}})",
        })
    {
        auto f = input.begin(), l = input.end();

        ast::value parsed;
        bool ok = phrase_parse(f, l, Parser::item, x3::space, parsed);

        if (ok) {
            std::cout << "Parsed: ";
            print(parsed);
            std::cout << "\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
        }

        if (f != l)
            std::cout << "Remaining unparsed: " << std::quoted(std::string{f, l}) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
Parsed: {
  "one",
  "five, six",
}
Parsed: {
  "one",
  {
    2,
    "three four",
  },
  "five, six",
  {
    "seven, eight",
  },
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but it does not seem to compile in boost versions v1.64.0 or later (currently v1.66.0). https://wandbox.org/permlink/7CNiNbMKAHlVq5iF

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention - that's a known issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48392993/how-to-make-a-recursive-rule-in-boost-spirit-x3-in-vs2017 - It's fixed in develop